# Closed Path in Graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

I am currently studying Graph Theory and I want an answer to this question :

We consider this path in a directed graph :  b->c , c->a , a->b . 
now i know that this path is called circuit

I wanted to know if there is a name or special label for this one : 
b->c , c->a , b->a .

Thanks .

Comment: That's not a path at all! The third step does not start where the second one ended.

Comment: Because it is not a path, you need to be much more specific about what class of objects you are trying to name.  Circuits can of course have $>3$ edges: can yours?  No way to tell from just one imprecisely-named example.

Comment: if i have a closed part of a graph with  more then 3 edges and the orientation of the edges dont form a circuit , does the closed path has a specific name ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is sometimes called a [transitive triangle](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0460).